# Blank window before all is loaded

Tags: c#, window-load

How do I code a blank window, [like this](http://spunit.tk/x/white.png), before the whole form is loaded? I've tried dragging a white picturebox over the window at Window_Load and Window_Shown, but that didn't work out. Any ideas?

Comment: could you mention the reason behind that, may be we can help you in a better way

Comment: My window looks kind of ugly when starting - and it takes a little time for all to load since it does a lot of things. Actually it lasts only for like 200 ms, but It bugs me. I just want to make it look nicer.

Comment: hahaha, I also had something like that before and I simply added another window with spinning shape until the busy one finish its work give me 2 min to find my code that was 4 years ago!

Comment: But doesn't that look weird if window 1 closes and another one opens when finished? Or maybe it doesn't shows like that?

Comment: the new window will show any thing that indicate that the program is loading and after the program done the load it will disappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made a custom window so when it shows up it would appear as a message box with custom appearance and when the loading done I close this window like that

```
CMessageBox cmb = new CMessageBox("Loading...");
cmb.Show(this);

//Do the heavy work here
//after the heavy work finish call cmb.close()

cmb.Close();
```

of course cmb is the custom window that you have to make your self

actually it is just a form that I have removed its borders and give it 'loading' text in the middle!

OK I will add the code for the custom form

Create a new form and add this code to it

```
public CMessageBox(string message)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.lblMessage.Text = message;
}

private void CMessageBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lblMessage.Top = (this.Height - this.lblMessage.Height) / 2;
    this.lblMessage.Left = (this.Width - this.lblMessage.Width) / 2;
}

private void lblMessage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lblMessage.Top = (this.Height - this.lblMessage.Height) / 2;
    this.lblMessage.Left = (this.Width - this.lblMessage.Width) / 2;
    this.Refresh();
}

public string _Caption
{
    get { return this.lblMessage.Text; }
    set { this.lblMessage.Text = value; }
}
```

After that you call it as I showed you at the beginning

I have set the window so it would have a small width and height just to contain the message, if you would like to change this you can ignore those 2 events

```
private void CMessageBox_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lblMessage.Top = (this.Height - this.lblMessage.Height) / 2;
    this.lblMessage.Left = (this.Width - this.lblMessage.Width) / 2;
}

private void lblMessage_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lblMessage.Top = (this.Height - this.lblMessage.Height) / 2;
    this.lblMessage.Left = (this.Width - this.lblMessage.Width) / 2;
    this.Refresh();
}
```

You need to add label in the design and give it a name lblMessage also you need to set the BorderStyle to none

Comment: I get errors from CMessageBox: The type or namespace name 'CMessageBox' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: oh man this is my own custom window implementation that I have made my self, you have to make your own ;), sorry I thought that was little clear I will edit my answer

Comment: I'm not very experienced at programming. I'd be happy if I could have the code, and to know where if should be placed. Thanks. =)

Comment: Ok I will add this for you just a min

Comment: I have added the code for the custom window, If it didn't works with you please inform me, if it works you can mark my answer as accepted:D

Comment: I hope that was helpful for you

Comment: for the sake of acceptance, for the question to be complete and the answer to be accepted you need to check the answer with a check to appear accepted(will have a green check) and other viewer for your question know that that your problem has been solved by the checked answer so they would be benefit from it. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Windows uses the painter's algorithm to draw, it goes from the back to the front.  So your PictureBox trick cannot work since it is the last one to be drawn.  The technical term is that it is highest in the Z-order.  Making it the lowest in the Z-order doesn't work either, it no longer covers the slow controls.

Trying to cover the controls isn't in general going to work anyway, removing the cover forces the controls to repaint themselves and you'll see the slow redraw at work again.  Technically you can cover it with another borderless form but that doesn't work on older Windows versions or ones that have Aero turned off.

You need another trick, still get the controls to paint but just not making it visible to the user.  Easily done with the Opacity property.  Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Opacity = 0;
    }
    protected override void OnShown(EventArgs e) {
        this.Update();
        this.Opacity = 0.99;
        base.OnShown(e);
    }
}
```

Your window will of course not be any faster to show up, it however now snaps onto the screen, giving the perception of speed.  Don't make the mistake of changing the Opacity assignment to 1.0, that makes it slow again because the window needs to be recreated and re-drawn.